# Getting SharedPreferences from Android app widget

Tags: android, widget, sharedpreferences

I'm building a simple widget which obtains data from SharedPreferences set in an Acitvity called ModifyInfo, but I can't figure out how to do it. The code below doesn't work for some reason that escapes me.

Error: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getSharedPreferences(String, int) from the type ContextWrapper.

```
public class WatchWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

@Override
public void onUpdate( Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds )
{
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews( context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout );
    ComponentName watchWidget = new ComponentName( context, WatchWidget.class );

    switch (Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK){
    case Calendar.MONDAY:
        SharedPreferences settings = ModifyInfo.getSharedPreferences("Monday", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText( R.id.widText, settings.getString("Monday", ""));
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget( watchWidget, remoteViews );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check that you open the `SharedPreferences` under the same name in both places (both the widget and the ModifyInfo activity). In the example above the name is "Monday".
2. Import `android.content.Context` and use `Context.MODE_PRIVATE` to get rid of the error

Comment: Thanks, fixed that part of the problem, though the code still won't compile. Error: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getSharedPreferences(String, int) from the type ContextWrapper.